# ¿Cómo acomodar un título en la parter superior de una segunda columna/sección?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Estoy tratando de formatear una página de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin las marcas rojas que provienen del ejercicio. Entonces probé el siguiente título :

```
<div class="container"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.sm="column"
    fxLayout.xs="column"
    fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
    fxLayoutGap="10px"
    fxLayoutGap.xs="0" >

    <div divFlex *ngIf="dish" fxFlex=40>
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <h3>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h3>
                </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src={{dish.image}} alt = {{dish.name}}>
            <mat-card-content>
                <p>{{dish.description}}
                </p>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>
                <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
                <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div divFlex *ngIf="dish" fxFlex=60>
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <h3>COMMENTS</h3>
                </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-list fxFlex>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments" >
                    <p matline>
                        <span>{{comment.comment}}
                            <br> {{comment.rating}} stars
                            <br>-- {{comment.author}} {{comment.date | date}}</span>
                    </p>
                </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list>
        </mat-card>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, incluso respetando el mismo efecto que para la imagen, no puedo poner el título COMMENTS en la parte superior de los comentarios.

¿Cómo poner un título en la parter superior de la sección de los comentarios?